# Auto post on facebook page as page admin with sdk4 (graph api)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I try to post to my facebook page via a website as the page admin. But I just can do that with my personnal account .

This is my code :

```
private $fb_api;
private $fb_secret;
private $fb_redirect = 'index.php/admin/ajout_actualite';
private $fb_helper;
private $fb_scopes   = array(/*'publish_actions', 'email', */'create_event', 'manage_pages', 'publish_stream');
private $fb_session;


$data = $this->config->item('facebook')['key'];

$this->fb_redirect = base_url($this->fb_redirect);



    $this->fb_api       = $this->config->item('facebook')['key'];
    $this->fb_secret    = $this->config->item('facebook')['secret'];
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($this->config->item('facebook')['key'], $this->config->item('facebook')['secret']);

    $this->fb_helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($this->fb_redirect);   
    if ( $this->session->userdata('access_token') ) {
        $this->fb_session = new FacebookSession( $this->session->userdata('access_token') );
        // Validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
        try {
            if ( ! $this->fb_session->validate() ) {
                $this->fb_session = false;
            }
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            // Catch any exceptions
            $this->fb_session = false;
        }
    }
```

And this is how I post on the page :

```
$loginUrl = $this->fb_helper->getLoginUrl($this->fb_scopes);       

    if($this->input->get('code') != null) {
        $s = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$this->fb_api."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($this->fb_redirect)."&client_secret=".$this->fb_secret."&code=".$this->input->get('code'));      

        $s = parse_str($s, $out);//var_dump($s);
        $this->session->set_userdata(array("access_token" => $out['access_token']));
    }else if($this->session->userdata('access_token') == NULL) {
        redirect($loginUrl);
    }

    if($this->fb_session != null){

    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
            $this->fb_session, 'POST', '/XXXXXXXX/feed', array(
                'name' => 'This is drop da bit',
                'caption' => "I love you baby",
                'link' => 'http://lesjoiesducode.fr/',
                'message' => 'Unicorn 1 - 0 Facebook'
                )
```

))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
}

I hope someone will can help me :), i've read 4-5 topics but there are in majority on the previous sdk :/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the **user access token** with the call `/{page-id}/feed` that's why the post is published on behalf of the user.

To post on behalf of the page itself, you have to use the [**page access token**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens). To get the page access token, add the permission `manage_pages` first to the login scope then make the call-

```
/{page-id}?fields=access_token
```

this will give you the page access token. To use this token with the `/{page-id}/feed` call just pass an additional parameter `access_token` with other parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your help but i don't understand what I have to do :/ 

I have to replace "/XXXXXXXX/feed" by "/{page-id}?fields=access_token" in $response (Where I send the data to my page) or before? And if it's before, where i've to do this ? 

Thanks again

Comment: Lol. In the call `/XXXXXXXX/feed` just use an additional parameter `access_token` and give it the value of `page access token`. And I've already explained how to get this `page access token` that's it!

Comment: ok so it's something like this : /1452962478282387/feed?fields=acces_token ? Where I replace acces_token by mine?

Comment: Where did I said `fields=access_token`? I dont know why but you are really confused with this super simple thing. I just said to add a parameter just like `name` `caption` etc...

Comment: God! I'm totally lost :( have you an example line of the request? :/

Comment: What's there to confuse? step-1: get the page access token with the `/{page-id}?fields=access_token` call. step-2: make post: `/{page-id}/feed?access_token={page-access-token-from-step-1}`. I dont know how else to explain you this.